# Pike: Is there a the Hilfe record file, and if yes, where is it?

Tags: pike

When running a hilfe session in a terminal and pressing the arrow up/down keys, I can reach the command I've previously fed to Hilfe. This is persistent between terminal sessions. I'm assuming there is a record file where the commands are saved. If my assumption is true, where can I find this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on linux and mac it's in your homedirectory named `.hilfe_history`

on windows it is in the USERPROFILE directory, also named `.hilfe_history`